# How to detect click events in a popover? (Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using a UITableViewController as a popover in my MainViewController. What I want to achieve is detect the tableview clicks and do some actions in my MainViewController. How do I achieve that?

This is how I create the popover:

```
let count = sender.dropdownItems?.count

let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
var menuViewController: MoreTableViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("moreTable") as! MoreTableViewController
menuViewController.data = sender.dropdownItems!

menuViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
menuViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 44*CGFloat(count!))

let popoverMenuViewController = menuViewController.popoverPresentationController
popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self
popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = sender
presentViewController(menuViewController,animated: true,completion: nil)
```

This is the MoreTableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class MoreTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //var data: [MoreItem]?

    var data = [MoreItem]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.scrollEnabled = false

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }



    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return data.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("moreCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MoreTableViewCell

        cell.label.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(17)
        cell.label.textColor = UIColor.init(hexString: MyConstants.COLOR_GREY)
        cell.label.text = data[indexPath.row].label


        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("Do something in MainViewController")
    }



}
```

Comment: did you mean pass data back to the previous view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cook,

You can make use of delegates.

In your MoreTableViewController add the protocol as

```
protocol LetsInformPreviousViewControllerProtocol : class {
    func cellTapped(WithIndex index : NSIndexPath) //pass whatever the data u want to pass to previous View controller here am passing indexPath of selected cell
}
```

and create a weak reference variable to hold the reference of delegate class.

```
weak var delegate : LetsInformPreviousViewControllerProtocol?
```

Finally in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.delegate?.cellTapped(WithIndex: indexPath) 
    }
```

And in your `MainViewController` confirm the protocol `LetsInformPreviousViewControllerProtocol` using

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, LetsInformPreviousViewControllerProtocol
```

and when you present `MoreTableViewController` say

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)
var menuViewController: MoreTableViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("moreTable") as! MoreTableViewController
menuViewController.delegate = self
```

Last step implement method cellTapped as

```
func cellTapped(WithIndex index: NSIndexPath) {
        print("\(index)")
    }
```

This will keep your code crash free and robust.

Avoid holding strong reference to ViewControllers which may lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can save the reference to the underlying ViewController in your MoreTableViewController.

In your MoreTableViewController add a variable

```
var underlyingMainViewController: MainViewController?
```

save the reference when presenting the MoreTableViewController:

```
presentViewController(menuViewController,animated: true){ _ in 
    menuViewController.underlyingMainViewController = self
}
```

then add some public functions to your MainViewController that you want to call:

```
func printFromMainViewController() {
    print("Hello from the MainViewController!")
}
```

and call them in your MoreTableViewController:

```
underlyingMainViewController?.printFromMainViewController()
```

Comment: You should never be holding the storng reference of another ViewController in your ViewCOntroller . Thats why you there are  delagets.

Comment: Thank you buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this too

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let mainViewController : MainViewController = self.presentingViewController as! MainViewController
        print("Do anything with mainViewControllerr")
    }
```